# Why does the IP address different for www.joinrealtalk.co & joinrealtalk.co

Tags: web, ip

I am trying to find the Ip address through which my emails are sent to check for Ip/ domain reputation.
Using all the tools, when I search for Ip addresses related to joinrealtalk.co, I get one value, and something else when I search for [www.joinrealtalk.co](http://www.joinrealtalk.co).

I'm assuming both the IPs should be the same for both these addresses right? Since it is the same domain.

Would really appreciate someone helping me understand why it is different, or if there is something fishy here.

Comment: *I'm assuming both the IPs should be the same for both these addresses right? Since it is the same domain.* - no.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers should be asked on [sf]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.